# ¿Por que mi Service Worker no funciona offline?

Tags: pwa, service-workers

Hola a todos buenas tardes, he estado haciendo un servicio web el cual quiero integrarlo a una PWA, he realizado los certificados SSL y ya los he configurado, he utilizado un código para el ServiceWorker junto con el manifest y un archivo para validar que el ServiceWorker funcione correctamente, hasta aquí todo muy bien, pero, cuando intento hacerlo funcionar offline sencillamente no carga, entonces a continuación mostrare todo el listado de archivos y errores que me aparecen en consola:

Primero que todo cuando entro al Devtools el sw funciona y está iniciado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Junto con la consola que no suelta ningún error cuando se está conectado a internet:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces, para hacer la prueba en modo offline, al dirigirme a la opción de Offline, al recargar la página me aparecen los siguientes errores en la consola:

Primero sigue apareciendo que el sw funciona:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero aparecen estos errores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En especifico son los siguientes:

```
VM9:7146 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.
(anonymous) @   VM9:7146
```

```
The FetchEvent for "https://.../" resulted in a network error response: the promise was rejected.
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ sw.js:50
```

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

Entonces, no sé por que pasa esto, apenas estoy iniciándome en este mundo de las PWA, de todas maneras les comparto los códigos de cada uno de los archivos:

Archivo de validación de funcionamiento del SW validacion.js

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('./sw.js')
        .then(reg => console.log('Registro de SW exitoso', reg))
        .catch(err => console.warn('Error al tratar de registrar el sw', err))
}
```

Archivo manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Nombre de la aplicacion",
    "short_name": "etc etc",
    "description": "etc etc",
    "background_color": "#FFFFFF",
    "theme_color": "#FFFFFF",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "display": "standalone",
    "start_url": "./?utm_source=web_app_manifest",
    "scope": "./",
    "lang": "es-MX",
    "icons": [{
            "src": "./img/icon_1024.png",
            "sizes": "1024x1024",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "./img/icon_512.png",
            "sizes": "512x512",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "./img/icon_384.png",
            "sizes": "384x384",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "./img/icon_256.png",
            "sizes": "256x256",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "./img/icon_192.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "./img/icon_128.png",
            "sizes": "128x128",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "./img/icon_96.png",
            "sizes": "96x96",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "./img/icon_64.png",
            "sizes": "64x64",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "./img/icon_32.png",
            "sizes": "32x32",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "./img/favicon.png",
            "sizes": "16x16",
            "type": "image/png"
        }
    ]
}
```

El archivo sw.js

```
;
//asignar un nombre y versión al cache
const CACHE_NAME = 'nombre',
    urlsToCache = [
        './',
        'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
        'https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css',
        'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css',
        './validacion.js',
        './img/forestal.png',
        './img/favicon.png'
    ]

//durante la fase de instalación, generalmente se almacena en caché los activos estáticos
self.addEventListener('install', e => {
    e.waitUntil(
        caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
        .then(cache => {
            return cache.addAll(urlsToCache)
                .then(() => self.skipWaiting())
        })
        .catch(err => console.log('Falló registro de cache', err))
    )
})

//una vez que se instala el SW, se activa y busca los recursos para hacer que funcione sin conexión
self.addEventListener('activate', e => {
    const cacheWhitelist = [CACHE_NAME]

    e.waitUntil(
        caches.keys()
        .then(cacheNames => {
            return Promise.all(
                cacheNames.map(cacheName => {
                    //Eliminamos lo que ya no se necesita en cache
                    if (cacheWhitelist.indexOf(cacheName) === -1) {
                        return caches.delete(cacheName)
                    }
                })
            )
        })
        // Le indica al SW activar el cache actual
        .then(() => self.clients.claim())
    )
})

//cuando el navegador recupera una url
self.addEventListener('fetch', e => {
    //Responder ya sea con el objeto en caché o continuar y buscar la url real
    e.respondWith(
        caches.match(e.request)
        .then(res => {
            if (res) {
                //recuperar del cache
                return res
            }
            //recuperar de la petición a la url
            return fetch(e.request)
        })
    )
})
```

Y dentro del head.php, cargo la siguiente información junto con un script:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=2.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="width">
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="./img/forestal.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="./forestal.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="./forestal.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json">
<title>Nombre</title>
<!-- css table datatables/dataTables -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

<!--Autocompletado de datos-->


<!--Calculos nomina-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/nomina.js"></script>

<script>
if('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
           .register('/sw.js')
           .then(function() { console.log("Service Worker Registered"); });
}
</script>
```

Por obvias razones los nombres de algunas de las páginas los he modificado por temas de confidencialidad, entonces no se que puede estar pasando, no tengo ni idea de por que se produce este error.

Como información adicional este desarrollo lo tengo alojado en Hostgator, no sé si se deba a este Hosting que se presente este problema, también tengo un servidor en Amazon AWS pero estuve viendo que Github nos permite también realizar esto con certificados de seguridad.

Con todo esto espero puedan ayudarme y muchísimas gracias a todos por las ayudas brindadas
Muchos saludos y buena suerte.

Comment: Hola me esta pasando lo mismo, lo solucionaste????

Answer (score 0):

Ahora Chrome genera una página offline por defecto que arregla ese problema: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/default-offline/

Si te interesa lo que estaba pasando era esto:

Como tienes programado el service worker no sabe como responder a tu request cuando estás offline. El service worker solo va a responder con lo que tienes en el cache, y si no lo encuentra en el cache va a ir a solicitarlo en la red.

En tu código no has cacheado nada para responder offline a nomina.exfor.co, nada más chequeas si esta en el cache y si no vas a la red.

En este caso tendrías que crear una repuesta por defecto a cuando estas offline y agregarla al cache, luego si este fetch falla, o sea el app está offline `fetch(e.request)`, respondes con la respuesta por defecto del cache.